# How to define array of strings in annotation parameter

Tags: php, symfony, swagger, nelmioapidocbundle

I'm working on API documentation with NelmioApiDoc bundle. All is fine and dandy except one thing: marking required fields in schema using annotation. 
I have following annotation:

```
[...]
  * @SWG\Parameter(
  *     name="Some parameter",
  *     in="body",
  *     required=true,
  *     @SWG\Schema(
  *         type="object",
  *         required="<how to put array of strings here?>",
  *         @SWG\Property(
  *             property="thisIsRequired",
  *             type="string",
  *         ),
  *         @SWG\Property(
  *             property="thisIsOptional",
  *             type="string",
  *         ),
[...]
```

I'd like to mark "thisIsRequired" as required. Using `required=true` on property is not correct way since it should be put on Schema level.

If I use yaml its all fine:

```
# packages/nelmio_api_doc.yaml
[...]
  schema:
    type: object
    required:
      - thisIsRequired
[...]
```

and required fields are correctly marked with red asterisk. I'm struggling with PHPDoc :/
I've tried with:

```
required="[\"thisIsRequired\"]", // wrong syntax
required=["thisIsRequired"]", // wrong syntax
required=array(\"thisIsRequired\"), // wrong syntax
required=array(thisIsRequired), // wrong syntax
required="array(\"thisIsRequired\")", // wrong syntax

required={"thisIsRequired"}, // no exception but doesnt mark field as required
required="[thisIsRequired]", // no exception but doesnt mark field as required
required="thisIsRequired", // no exception but doesnt mark field as required
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is proper syntax:

```
required={"thisIsRequired", "otherField"},
```

I probably didn't clear cache after that one try. Remember kids always clear your cache after the changes! ;)